# Filter C# Entity List

Tags: c#, list, filter, entity

Hi to the helpfull community!

Guys I have a problem with a C# Entity/SQL Server 2014 project that gives me hard times

I have a procedure with this result set

```
OnDate          RoomType    Available   RateCode Price
2016-12-12      DBL         2           BAR      200
2016-12-12      TRP         4           BAR      300
2016-12-12      DBL         2           NEW      250
2016-12-12      TRP         4           NEW      350
```

In my C# program I have a List that is fed from that procedure through the Entyity Framework

In order not to create another procedure and another LIST, is there a way, depending on my needs, to transform my List result within C# as follows?

```
OnDate          RoomType    Available   RateCode Price
2016-12-12      DBL         2                       0
2016-12-12      TRP         4                       0
```

So it is basically the same result but DISTINCT with the RateCode empty and the Price = 0

I need both results sets for my processing. I do for loops and populate XMLs so when I need only RoomType-Availability if I am stuck with the first result I would get the same Room Types as many tmes as RateCodes exist which is not acceptable

```
for (int Row = 0; Row < myList.Count(); Row++)
{
   blah
}
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Why the price should be 0 ? Probably should be the sum of the 2 rows ? Also you should choose what to be your RateCode.

Comment: I need it as 0 in order to get the Distinct RoomTypes - Availability which does not change whichever RateCode is used.

Comment: You can do that with GroupBy for your collection, I will write you something how to do it.

Comment: You can check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return your desired list. You are grouping your collection by `RoomType` and Available and after that `Select` the data which you need.

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => new { x.RoomType, x.Available })
                    .Select(g => new Hotel { 
                                             OnDate = g.First().OnDate, 
                                             RoomType = g.Key.RoomType, 
                                             Available = g.Key.Available, 
                                             RateCode = "", 
                                             Price = 0 })
                    .ToList();
```

Here full code example: [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvukOl)